# Access denied to write a file with my C # WCF webService

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, exception, permissions

I hosted a WCF web Service on my server **Windows 2008 R2**. 
Everything works perfectly on my localhost project **Visual Studio 2012**.

However, once deployed on my server. My application throws an exception when my WCF trying to save an XML file in the C:\.

I immediately think it came from a permissions problem. I've tried adding rights in writings on the user **IUSR** but it changed nothing. I even tried to apply all the rights to the user "Everyone". But without success!
An idea ? thanks

Here's screenshots of on the configuration of my project:

[image]

[image]

Code that throws the exception:

```
XmlTextWriter myXmlTextWriter = new XmlTextWriter("c:/world.xml", null);
```

Comment: Whoa! You just! I had not thought of that. In fact I do not understand why ^ ^. But if I change the path to a subdirectory of the root directory everything works perfectly. Thank you so much.
Can you add it as an answer?

Comment: Yeh sure I'll post it as an answer for people :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you saving to the root drive folder? What happens when you try and save to for example `C:\Stuff`?

If this isn't running as something like `Network Service` I would hazard a guess it's because of something like UAC which will prevent you from writing to certain places considered restricted.

Comment: Thank you very much! Once the path is changed on a sub-folder of the root directory, everything works perfectly. ^^